# What are the correct Google Webmaster URL Parameter settings for Pagination and Sorting?

Tags: magento, google-search-console

We have about 4,000 products in a store, but Google is monitoring 31,000 URLS.  To try and reduce the number of indexed pages, I have restricted the URL parameters in webmaster admin to:

- LIMIT = All
- P = 1
- DIR = Asc

I'm thinking this will reduce the category pages indexed to 1 instance of each category.

The site has canonical URL tags defined, a comprehensive robots.txt and a daily updated sitemap.

Is this acceptable or is it better to Let Google Decide?

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you are comfortable with what we decide is better for your site, then it's better to leave it to us. That said, if Googlebot is creating problems with crawling irrelevant or duplicate URLs, then of course, go ahead and create the filters.

Other than that, it's often much better to actually just disallow crawling the URLs if you can. That's less error prone and it will decrease the traffic to the roboted pages for good.

And finally, to actually answer your question, that setup looks good to me, although without knowing the exact URLs it's hard to say for sure.